# Why can't I use anything I download/Why can't I download Ubuntu restricted?

Tags: downloads, restricted-access, ubuntu-restricted-extras

I'm a new user to Linux in general and I'm trying to download Ubuntu restricted add-ons package and I'm having trouble downloading anything.

My computer said to download Adobe installer and I did, but I can't finish the installation because my computer is showing the files in a different form than I'm used to, and I'm very confused. Any ideas on what's wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: Download ubuntu-restricted-extras from Ubuntu Software Center or Synaptic. How are you downloading such files?

Comment: When I go to download from Ubuntu software center, It tells me I need to open it WITH something else. I'm honestly not sure what I'm doing, but I'm not computer illiterate. I'm just used to windows

Comment: What Adobe program are you trying to install?

Answer (score 0):

To install Ubuntu Restricted Extras, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```